Why is there a Monad typeclass constraint when a less strict Functor constraint would suffice?
I am looking at the source code of the StateT monad transformer
There are two functions execStateT and evalStateT that have a Monad m constraint in their definitions:
evalStateT :: Monad m => StateT s m a -> s -> m a
evalStateT m s = do
  ~(a, _) <- runStateT m s
  return a

execStateT :: Monad m => StateT s m a -> s -> m s
execStateT m s = do
  ~(_, s') <- runStateT m s
  return s'

Wouldn't this implementation using a Functor constraint also work?
evalStateT :: Functor m => StateT s m a -> s -> m a
evalStateT = (fmap fst .) . runStateT

execStateT :: Functor m => StateT s m a -> s -> m s
execStateT = (fmap snd .) . runStateT

Is there a reason why a stricter constraint is applied?

Probably because development of the package started in 2009, when the Functor Applicative Monad (FAM) proposal was not yet completed IIRC.

Hard to tell -- my guess is that we need Monad m anyway for any actual use of StateT. Without that, there's very little we can do with StateT. Thinking of StateT s m as something that enables different primitives depending on m being a functor or monad requires more cognitive effort for very little gain. It's easier to ignore the generality and just assume Monad m is needed everywhere. (And, if really needed, we can define the functor-based versions of those primitives anyway -- the API allows for that)


Is there a reason why a stricter constraint is applied?

It is hard to tell, but there are two reasons that come to mind:

It does not make much sense to work with it as a Functor: a monad transformer only makes much sense to use it to transform a monad. So eventually evalStateT will (nearly) always work on something with m a instance of Monad because the thing that constructed the StateT s m a in the first place required m to be a Monad; and

The Monad type constraint was already implemented in transformers-0.0.0.0 [Hackage] back in January 2009. At that time the Functor-Applicative-Monad proposal [Haskell-wiki] was not yet made (that was in 2014). So that means that by that time, a Monad was not a subclass of Applicative, and Applicative was not a subclass of Functor. As a result a type T could be an instance of Monad without being an instance of Functor or Applicative.
So by adding Functor as type constraint, you actually often made it a bit worse: some types that were instances of Monad were not instances of Functors yet, and therefore you could thus exclude certain types that could still be useful for a StateT. The fact that a Monad type did not require to be an instance of Applicative and Functor was always a bit of a misfeature, but it took some while to undo the damage.


